# how to add a printer in i3

Tags: i3

I am using the [i3 tiling window manager](https://i3wm.org/). How can I add a printer (e.g. things like searching the network to auto-discover printers to connect to or supply a printer's coordinates). Unfortunately "i3 printer" is not very google-able as an actual printer named `i3` exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`i3` is a window manager, not a desktop environment. If you want a desktop environment, you'll have to add one; many DEs do support changing their window manager.

If you just want to add a printer, you don't need to use an `i3`-specific tool to do so. You can just use whatever *other* desktop's tools; or you can bypass them all and go directly to cups. This is done by pointing your webbrowser to http://localhost:631/ and configuring things there.

If cups asks you for a username and password, note that cups is usually configured to use PAM for authentication. You can either use `root` and your root password to log in, or add a user to the group which is configured with the `SystemGroup` statement in `cups-files.conf` (on Debian and derivatives, this is the `lpadmin` group).

Comment: To add this you can run i3 over a Desktop Environment like MATE (GNOME2) or LXDE which will set much of this sort of thing up for you.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the CUPS web interface (http://localhost:631/), but there exist a handful of CUPS GUIs you may prefer instead.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#GUI_applications

I have not found a good tray icon/tool yet, however.

Comment: Thanks. Precise and direct instructions. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using i3, my notes on adding a network printer without a GUI interface:

```
pacman -S cups
systemctl enable --now cups

# Add printer(eg ip: 10.2.3.4)
# -p printer name
# -E Enable and accept jobs on the printer (after -p)
# -v device-uri
# -m driver('everywhere' should work on most printers)
lpadmin -p konica1 -E -v ipp://10.2.3.4/ipp/print -m everywhere

# Delete a printer
lpadmin -x konica1

# View installed printers in cups interface
http://localhost:631/printers/

# View installed printer from cmdline:
lpstat -p
```